# How to use common table expression in a dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

I have to write a dynamic pivot based on a complex query and I want to use a common table expression to create the dataset on which I have to build the pivot to keep it outside the dynamic sql and have it compiled

My problem is that I don't know if i can use the CTE in a SET where I wrap the dynamic SQL I have to execute.

let see the code:

```
WITH DatiCTE AS
    (
    SELECT ...
    )

    SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
          N'SELECT IdActivity, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
    FROM DatiCTE
    PIVOT(SUM(NumOfDays) 
          FOR Area IN (' + @PivotColumnNames + ')) AS PVTTable'
          WHERE 1 = 1

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

This way i get an error near `SET @DynamicPivotQuery =`

If I replace SET with a SELECT the stored procedure is compiled but if i run it I get:

```
Invalid object name 'DatiCTE'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for now i switch to temp table:

```
SELECT ...
INTO @TempTable

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'
    SELECT IdActivity, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
    FROM @TempTable
    PIVOT(SUM(NumOfDays) 
      FOR Area IN (' + @PivotColumnNames + ')) AS PVTTable'
      + 'WHERE 1 = 1';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery;
```

but i have soume doubt about concurrent users. i try table variable but cant be used in dynamic sql...

Answer (score 4):

Move the definition of the CTE `WITH DatiCTE AS` to be inside the dynamic sql like this:

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'WITH DatiCTE AS
    (
       SELECT ...
    )
    SELECT IdActivity, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
    FROM DatiCTE
    PIVOT(SUM(NumOfDays) 
      FOR Area IN (' + @PivotColumnNames + ')) AS PVTTable'
      + 'WHERE 1 = 1';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery;
```

Comment: the scope of the CTE is to keep the costant code outside of the dynamic SQL

Comment: Why is this answer upvoted? It does not work.